# Lenovo S10 BCM 4312 (rev 01) WiFi not functioning

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I have just created LiveUSB 3 days ago and have been reading the forums here about getting WiFi card to work. Here is what I have done so far:

Ran:

```
sudo apt-­get update
```

Ran:

```
sudo apt­-get upgrade
```

Ran:

```
sudo-apt get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Found this thread: [Before posting in Networking & Wireless - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108)

Then ran:

```
wget ­-N ­-t 5 -­T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
```

and ran `lspci` and got this:

```
Network Controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP­-PHY (rev 01)
```

On "Preferences→Additional Drivers", it reads: Broadcom corporation: BCM4312 802.11b/g

This device is not working (beneath this are two selections and the 2nd one is highlighted):

> Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl­kernal- source(proprietary)
>
> Do not use this device

Of note: I saw a page that listed upgrades for various cards and the 4312 was listed but not the rev 01.

Here is the output of the wireless script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux lubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0241 Acer, Inc BisonCam, NB Pro
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13fe:4100 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

b43                   356470  0 
bcma                   42043  1 b43
mac80211              545990  1 b43
cfg80211              409394  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    51854  1 b43

##### iw reg get #####

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search dc.dc.cox.net

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.114
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

##### iwlist channel #####

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     BED87D210887FFC71A4BDE0
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Dcl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev18cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev17cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev11cl*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev10*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0F*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0D*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0C*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0B*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0A*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev09*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev07*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev06*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev05*
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:96:DC:92:B0:1D:75:9D:3E:85:62:EA:32:A1:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004365sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004358sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004313sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00000576sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:96:DC:92:B0:1D:75:9D:3E:85:62:EA:32:A1:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004325sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004324sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004322sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004321sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004319sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014A4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:96:DC:92:B0:1D:75:9D:3E:85:62:EA:32:A1:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x1713 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #####

[   12.748344] ssb: Found chip with id 0x4312, rev 0x01 and package 0x00
[   12.748375] ssb: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (cc 0x800, rev 0x16, vendor 0x4243)
[   12.748399] ssb: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (cc 0x812, rev 0x0F, vendor 0x4243)
[   12.748421] ssb: Core 2 found: PCMCIA (cc 0x80D, rev 0x0A, vendor 0x4243)
[   12.748444] ssb: Core 3 found: PCI-E (cc 0x820, rev 0x09, vendor 0x4243)
[   12.829172] ssb: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:05:00.0
[   45.398043] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[   45.463937] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[   45.491892] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   45.491906] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[   46.494989] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   46.495003] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[   46.673972] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   46.673986] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[   46.704647] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   46.704660] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[   46.772913] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
[   46.772918] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
[   46.772924] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please paste the wireless script results here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ that were created when you ran ./wireless-script. Edit your question to give us the link.

Comment: done. see hyperlink above. Its entitled "enter link description here" but it takes you to the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your wireless_script:

> b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found

It appears that the installation of firmware has failed. With the ethernet connected and an internet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

It should now be working.

There should be no need to enter any settings in 'Network Coonections.' If you click the Network Manager icon, you should see a list of networks to choose from. Click yours and you should be asked for your WPA2 password. Enter it and connect. Please see: [http://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu(1).png](http://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu%281%29.png)

Comment: did as you instructed but suspect that I am also not entering network settings in Network Manager properly as I'm new to configuring networks. Found a walkthrough with screencaptures on version 0.7 here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager0.7/ but my version is 0.9.8.8 Wondering if there is a page covering the newer version. Clicked on "help" in network setings but this appeared: "Failed to execute child process "gnome-help" (No such file or directory)"

Comment: cont'd: Am trying to connect to wireless D-Link router using WPA2 scurity setting. Clicked "add WiFi" in dropdown menu of "Preferences-> Network Connections" and the WiFi" with "mode" "chanel", etc..and "IPv4 setings" tab with six "method" settings to choose from.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you very much for following-up w/ me. That was one issue that seemed to be a deal breaker, as far as making Lubuntu 14.04 LTS my next permanent OS on this older netbook as MS Win XP is no longer supported. Now I'll have to check my old files on MS XP to see if theres any thing I need to save before permanently installing Lubuntu. Right now I' booting using the Live USB interface from http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ but it doesn't seem to save my settings??? everytime I power it down. It does offer the option to "install" on boot-up but haven't done that yet.

Comment: In order to get your settings to save, you need 'persistence.' In other words part of the USB drive is set aside for such settings to be saved. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence If my answer has solved your question, please accept it.

Comment: ok. I believe I credited you w/ the answer by clicking the check mark beneath the "up/down" vote selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Im on ubuntu 15. My old dell inspiron would not recognize my bcm 4312 14e4 4315 rev01 wireless adater so this is the only thing that worked but u need wired connection to install b43

First off

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Select all option check boxes available Make sure wired connection is plugged in

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Next do all

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe -r wl
```

Module wl not found is possible

Next

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

Wait a few moments and check for wireless activity now. Airplane mode was turned on qen i did it i turned off airplane n the wifi worked for the first time ever . This was ubuntu live usb setup so i needed to switch to b43 instead of reboot but it works better i think. I prefer to stick with live os anyway if im installing os i just stick to windows